# VIM uppercase autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I switched to vim after using Eclipse for many years. One feature which I really miss in vim is upper-case based autocompletion.

E.g. when I type `SetMWL <ctrl-N>` I would like that vim also suggests `SetMaximumWordLength` for camel-case and set_maximum_word_length for snake_case.

I've also looked for plugins but couldn't find one with this feature.

Comment: See `:help 'infercase'` and `:help complete-functions`

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for. That feature just adjust the upper/lower cases of the match with the typed text

Comment: [coc-nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) has that feature.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve your demand is using plugins and [maralla/completor.vim](https://github.com/maralla/completor.vim) is one of the plugins which has the functionality.

Although Vim itself doesn't have that kind of functionality by default, you can implement your own completion method using `complete()` function, but it is not easy.